# How to use parameters in read_sql_query SQL query in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to use two dates as parameters. My sql query isn't recognizing the parameter markings that I am using. I am getting this error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql ' Select top 2 * from
> search_source_202206 where CAST(search_start_user_action_server_ts AS
> DATE) between  '?' and '?' ': ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers,
> but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

```
   import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import pyodbc
    
    CONN_STR = r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=SQLIPMDS\SQLI;Database=Analytics;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    
sqlString = """
Select top 2 *
from search_source_202206
where CAST(search_start_user_action_server_ts AS DATE) between  ? and ?
"""

    with pyodbc.connect(CONN_STR) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query(sqlString,con=con,params= ['2022-06-06','2022-06-07'])
    
    df
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to show how sqlString was defined

Comment: `between '?' and '?'` are the question marks really in quotes?

Comment: `'?'` is a string literal. Try using `… between ? and ?`

Comment: @GordThompson I have tried both ways and still errors.

Comment: Is the error message the same when you try `...between ? and ?`

Comment: maybe this database needs `%` or `%s` instead of `?`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/tctM59sE) works for me.